# c++ winApi ComboBox определение позиции курсора в выпадающем списке

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте, друзья! Разбираюсь с возможностями с++ winApi. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно отследить в раскрывшемся списке combobox над каким пунктом находится курсор мышки?

Comment: А что, [CB_GETCURSEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775845(v=vs.85).aspx) не работает?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста код, который воспроизводит проблему.